# How to use generic type parameters in a c# interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, parameters

I have

```
public interface IPersistedModel<TModel, TIdentifier>
```

I'd like to define an interface where I have a generic method that uses the generic type parameters from the above.  Is there a way to do this?  I've tried the following but neither compiles.

```
public interface IModelCollection1<IPersistedModel<TModel, TIdentifier>>
{
    IEnumerable<TModel> ReadCollection(TIdentifier identifier);
}
```

or

```
public interface IModelCollection2<T> where T : IPersistedModel<TModel, TIdentifier>
{
    IEnumerable<TModel> ReadCollection(TIdentifier identifier);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you need to include the generic types in the interface itself:

```
public interface IModelCollection<T, TModel, TIdentifier> 
       where T : IPersistedModel<TModel, TIdentifier>
{
    IEnumerable<TModel> ReadCollection(TIdentifier identifier);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a generic method which adds generic parameters only to that method

```
class A
{

static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
{
    T temp;
    temp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = temp;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public interface Ione <T, U> where T : IInterfaceOne<T> where U : IInterfaceTwo<U>
{

}

public interface IInterfaceOne<T>
{

}

public interface IInterfaceTwo<U>
{

}
```